# Can I use a single for loop for two different declared objects?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
 public void SetupShip()
    {
        ship1 = new Ship("Olympic Countess");
        ArrayList groupA = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupA.Add(new room(5000, "A" + (i + 1)));
        }
        ArrayList groupB = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupB.Add(new room(4000, "B" + (i + 1)));
        }
    }
```

Instead of using same conditions to loop different objects as done above, Can I add that new room within the same loop, as the looping condition is the same. Thanks.

Comment: yes you can use it

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work

```
public void SetupShip()
    {
        ship1 = new Ship("Olympic Countess");
        ArrayList groupA = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList groupB = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupA.Add(new room(5000, "A" + (i + 1)));
            groupB.Add(new room(4000, "B" + (i + 1)));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not use an *obsolete* `ArrayList`, but `List<room>`; 
If you need to *generate* items, then generate them:

```
public void SetupShip() {
  ship1 = new Ship("Olympic Countess");

  List<room> groupA = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 9)
    .Select(i => new room(5000, "A" + i))
    .ToList();

  List<room> groupB = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 9)
    .Select(i => new room(4000, "B" + i))
    .ToList();
}
```

P.S. Sure you can add *two* items in the *same* loop, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  groupA.Add(new room(5000, "A" + (i + 1)));
  groupB.Add(new room(4000, "B" + (i + 1)));
}
```

but I suggest not doing that but *generating* the list.